# Security error in Firefox WebExtension when trying getUrl image

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Trying to port some Chrome extension and getting this *Security Error: Content at "http://example.com" may not load or link
to "moz-extension://04d69802-c26f-47ae-86f2-d54650455e5a/blocks/indicators/__icon/indicators__icon-tweet.png"*

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
   var PATHS = {
    TWITTER: chrome.extension.getURL("blocks/indicators/__icon/indicators__icon-tweet.png")
   };
})();
```

In *manifest.json* this path is in *web_accessible_resources*.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but did you tryed loading though a request? You can skip cross origin if you have hogh privileges: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request

Comment: I'm trying to do this with WebExtension API, so It still will be compatible with Chrome-like browsers. And this resource is available, if I type it URL in searchbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of this error, full path should be provided.

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
   "blocks/indicators/__icon/indicators__icon-tweet.png"
]
```

No `"blocks/indicators/*`.